# How can I make an HTML box slide on hover and reveal the text underneath it using JS or CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I have been for long trying to make an HTML box slide on hover and reveal the text beneath it using CSS or JS. I am new to JavaScript so it would be great if you provide a bit of explanation with the answer if its to be achieved by JS.

I have searched many sites and asked a lot of people but I haven't been able to achieve it.

I have made two DIVs, one being underneath the other

I tried writing some example text, but it appears before the box

```css
.trigger{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 5px solid #999;
background: #ddd; 
position: relative;
}
.box{
display: inline-block;
background: pink;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
pointer-events: none;
position: absolute;
}
.trigger:hover .box{
transform: translate(100px, 75px) rotate(40deg) ;
        }
```

```html
<div class="trigger">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add a `z-index`:

```css
.trigger {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid #999;
  background: #ddd; 
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background: pink;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.trigger:hover .box {
  transform: translate(100px, 75px) rotate(40deg) ;
}
```

```html
<div class="trigger">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```